# What's wrong with my mount? I am trying to mount and allow read-write

Tags: debian, mount, fstab

`/etc/fstab`

```
/srv/www/test.com  /home/user/test.com auto nouser,auto,rw,sync 0 0
```

I am getting the following error: `mount: you must specify the filesystem type`. Could someone please give me some insight? I am trying to mount a directoryA into directoryB and allow any changes (add new files, edit files). Also, if I make changes to a file in the mount, it would automatically change the original right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mount` attaches a device node (physical disk, remote nfs mount, etc.) to a directory.  What you're trying to do is map one directory to another directory.  There are a few ways to handle this.

The most common is called a symbolic link.  It essentially creates a filesystem entry that redirects to another location within the filesystem.  If you simply want user to be able to access the document root of test.com from inside his home directory, this is the most simple approach.

Alternatively, you can use the `bind` mount type.  You must be sure that the target directory exists before you use this type, or you won't get the results you're expecting.  This can be done at the commandline with:

```
mount --bind /src/www/test.com /home/user/test.com
```

If you want to add it to the `/etc/fstab` file, it would look like:

```
/srv/www/test.com  /home/user/test.com bind defaults,bind 0 0
```

However, I'd carefully consider why a symbolic link isn't sufficient before dealing with `bind` mounts.

Comment: It's because I `chroot` them to the home.

Comment: That's a valid reason to use a bind mount in my book :-)

Comment: Take great care when removing a chroot tree. `rm -rf` **will** descend into a bind mount.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is a symbolic link:

```
ln -s /srv/www/test.com  /home/user/test.com
```

See `man ls`.

Comment: I cannot make changes to a mount?

Comment: You cannot mount a directory, just a complete file system, so the whole line in `/etc/fstab` doesn't make any sense.  `ln` is the way to do what you want. Just try it.